# Array size calculation without using inbuilt functions

Tags: c

How do I find the size of an integer array without using any inbuilt (standard) functions? Here's my attempt at it:

```
int fun(int a[25],int ele)
{

    int flag=0,i=0;
    while(a[i]!=NULL)
    {
        flag++;
        i++;
    }
    return flag;
 }
```

Comment: note: `a[i]!=NULL`...don't. `a[i]` is not a pointer, but NULL is.

Comment: Simple: `return 25;`

Comment: If you found one of the answer helpful you may [want to consider accepting one of them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 8):

The most common way of sending data around in arrays is by null-terminating the arrays. (However, this may not work for you if, for example, `0` is a valid integer to have in your array. In this case, you might want to use `-1`, for example.)

```
int array_len(int *arr)
{
    const int TERMINATOR = 0; // or -1, as the case may be
    int i = 0;
    while (arr[i] != TERMINATOR)
        i++;
    return i;
}
```

However, a better method is probably just sending not *only* an array, but an array *and* a length whenever passing around data. That way, you don't need to keep calling functions like this to get array lengths in your various functions.

Comment: for that matter all the empty cells of that array should have 0.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

The behaviour on going past the bounds of the array is undefined.

You could model the array with some sort of value acting as a terminator, but that's hardly practical. Pass the size as an extra parameter, of if you really want to have just one argument, use a `struct`.

Comment: @P45Imminent Having an array terminator *is* practical. In fact, it's one of the *best* ways in C to do this.

Comment: @Jashaszun If only you could somehow store the size information, you know, like an extra variable or parameter.

Comment: @this Read my answer. That's exactly what I say. That's also why I said in the comment above that it's **one** of the best ways. The *other* best way is to pass the size as a separate argument.

Comment: @Jashaszun I was replying on your comment and not the answer.

Comment: "some sort of value acting as a terminator, but that's hardly practical.",  Hmmm, C strings use a terminating null character - 43 years of impracticality?

Answer (score 3):

C does not store the size of the array with it. In C strings a NULL terminator is used to determine the size of the array, but this is convention. Either pass the size as an argument to the function, or choose a value that is considered the end of the array and search for it.

Comment: `C does not store the size of the array with it.`.. is it?

Comment: Your answer is subtly wrong. Calling `sizeof` on an array will properly output the size of the whole structure. The problem is that arrays *decay* when passed to functions; the parameter you get is a pointer which knows nothing about the underlying array. I think you have the right idea, but this point could stand to be clarified, as it is a common source of confusion.

Comment: Arrays passed to functions are converted to pointers. See  http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c

Comment: @acwaters. Were you talking about my post? I did not mention sizeof().

Comment: @RobertJacobs I was wrong to say your answer was wrong. You didn't mention it, and I don't believe you meant to cause confusion, but your statement "C does not store the size of the array with it" could easily be misinterpreted to mean that there is no way to determine the size of an array in C, which is a fairly common misconception already among beginners who are just learning about array decay. It would be better to not mention sizing arrays at all, since what's being passed *isn't* an array, and instead to make it clear that what's being passed is in fact a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In you `while` loop condition -

```
while(a[i]!=NULL)//replace NULL with such value which is unique and not used in your array.
```

Use `-1` or something.

You may think to use `'\0'` instead of `NULL`  but then if your array has `0` in between also then also loop will stop. (if `0` is in array don't use `'\0'`).